# Mootools overlay fade in

Tags: mootools, mootools1.2, mootools-events

Hi how do you make a div fade in nicely in mootools?

```
var el = $$('div.img_wrapper');

el.addEvents({
    mouseenter: function(){
        fade in div
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        fade out div
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mouseenter: function(){
  this.fade('in');
}, 

//this can't be zero or the mouseenter won't fire
mouseleave: function(){
  this.fade(.001);   
}
```